# Effects of Dielectric on the Electrostatic Potential Inside a Capacitor

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, capacitance, dielectric

Let's consider two identical capacitors (same geometry) with the same applied DC voltage, but with different dielectrics.

Is the electrostatic potential function V (y) (with y = distance with respect to one of the two plates) the same in both cases? If yes,  which is the physical reason for this independence from the dielectric?

Comment: When you say electrostatic potential function, do you mean the potential difference, or voltage, between the capacitor plates?

Comment: Not exactly: it is the voltage between each point of the surrounding space and one plate we may assume as reference (if we evaluate it at the position of the other plate, we get the voltage between them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the potential difference will be the same. If you consider a parallel plate capacitor, the field between the plates is just $E = \Delta V / h$, where $h$ is the distance between the plates. The two fields $E_1$ and $E_2$ are the same, since the two capacitors have the same applied DC voltage ($\Delta V$) and the same geometry (hence the same $h$). Therefore, the potential difference between one plate and any other point, being just the line integral of the field, will be the same. Are the two systems just the same then? No, of course they are not. Since they are filled with different dielectrics, their capacities are different, $C_1$ and $C_2$. This means that the *charge* on the plates will be different, being given by

$$
q_1 = C_1 \Delta V
$$

and

$$
q_2 = C_2 \Delta V.
$$

In other words, the voltage source will have to place a different amount of charge on the different capacitors, proportional to their capacity.

Comment: Is it correct to calculate the potential difference between one plate and any other point by using the electric field E = ∆V/h? I thought it was an average electric field, while we should use the electric field as function of position

Comment: @Kinka-Byo The electric field between the plates of a capacitor is considered to be constant (ignoring fringe effects at the edges of the plates).

Answer (score 0):

> Is the electrostatic potential function V (y) (with y = distance with
>   respect to one of the two plates) the same in both cases?

No

The potential difference (voltage) $V$ is defined as the work required per unit charge to move the charge between the points. So the potential as a function of the distance $y$ from one of the plates is

$$V(y)=Ey$$

And therefore the potential difference between the plates  separated by distance d is

$$V=Ed$$

The effective electric field $E$ between the plates due to polarization of the dielectric is

$$E=\frac{σ}{kε_0}$$

So

$$V=\frac{σd}{kε_0}$$

where $k$ is the dielectric constant for the specific dielectric used, and $ε_0$ is the permittivity of free space, and $σ$ charge per unit area. The higher the dielectric constant the lower the voltage.

The reason the electric field, and thus voltage, is less with a different dielectric is that different dielectrics involve different degrees of polarization of the material depending on the dielectric constant, $k$. The larger $k$ the greater the polarization of the medium. The polarization in turn produces an electric field a opposing the field produced by the charges on the plates. This effectively reduces the effective electric field. With a reduced field it requires less work per unit charge (voltage) to move the charge between two points.  That, in turn, increases the capacitance since

$$C=\frac{q}{V}$$

For more complete background on the effect of the dielectric on the electric field of a capacitor, google "Dielectric" and check out the Hyperphysics web site.

Hope this helps